# HTML5: Canvas performs too slow on lower end computers

Tags: javascript, optimization, html, canvas, performance

My problem is that my javascript/canvas performs very slowly on lower end computers (Even though they can run even more challenging [canvas](http://9elements.com/io/projects/html5/canvas/) [scripts](http://www.benjoffe.com/code/demos/canvascape/) smoothly).
I'm trying to do a simple animation depending on user selection.

When drawing on the canvas directly proved to be too slow, I draw on a hidden canvas and saved all frames (`getImageData`) to `data` and then called `animate(1);` to draw on my real canvas.

```
function animate(i){
    if(i < 12){
        ctx2.putImageData(data[i], 0, 0);
        setTimeout(function(){animate(i+1)},1);
    }
}
```

But even this is too slow. What do I do?

Comment: I believe Canvas implementations use back buffers so you don't actually gain anything with a hidden canvas object.

Comment: _"Some computers are slow, what do I do?"_ a) Do what you can to make your code more efficient, b) Accept the limitations of what you are trying to do. So far your responses to answers below make it appear that you are unwilling to do either of the above.

Comment: Start simple first. Write a `for` loop that just loops through `i` and does the `putImageData`. How fast is that? And if it's not fast enough, what does that tell you about `putImageData` ?

Answer (score 7):

1. Do not use `putImageData` if you can help it. The performance on FF3.6 [is abysmal](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_copy_benchmark.html):
   [image: Test results showing poor getImageData performance]
   <sub>(source: [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_copy_benchmark.png))</sub>

Use drawing commands on off-screen canvases and blit sprites to sub-regions using `drawImage` instead.

2. As mentioned by @MartinJespersen, rewrite your frame drawing loop:

   ```
   var animate = function(){
     // ...
     setTimeout(animate,30); //Max out around 30fps
   };
   animate();
   ```
3. If you're using a library that forces a `clearRect` every frame, but you don't need that, stop using that library. Clear and redraw only the portions you need.
4. Use a smaller canvas size. If you find it sufficient, you could even scale it up using CSS.
5. Accept that slow computers are slow, and you are standing on the shoulders of a great many abstraction layers. If you want to eek out performance for low-end computers, write in C++ and OpenGL. Otherwise, set minimum system requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The timeout you specified is 1 millisecond. No browser can update the canvas that fast. Change it to 1000 - that'll be 1 second, i.e:

```
setTimeout(function(){animate(i+1)}, 1000)
```

---

**UPD.** Another thing to try is to prepare as many canvases as there are frames in your animation, set all of them to `display:none`, then turn `display:block` on them sequentially. I doubt it's going to be faster than putImageData, but still worth trying.

Comment: I know, but the more I increase it the slower the animation gets (obviously). I figure; at 1 it's trying as fast as it can, but it's still too slow.

Comment: Hmm.. the faster you animate the more load on the proccessor it puts. Try to find an optimal timeout. 20 to 100 milliseconds sounds reasonable.

Comment: It's slow BECAUSE you set it to 1 ms. Try setting it somewhere between 10 or 20 ms (maybe even higher) to find the balance between performance and the smoothness of the animation.

Comment: Again, increasing the timeout does not increase the animation speed.

Comment: @abloddywar; You are missing the point - it doesn't matter if what you try to do, updating a canvas or making simple calculations - each setTimeout call creates a new callstack - trying to do that every millisecond is bound to be slow, no matter what. You have to change your approach or you will never get a result that you like.

Comment: Low end computers cannot even match a 100 millisecond timeout.

Answer (score 2):

1. As already mentioned timeouts with 1 millisecond interval are doomed to fail, so the first step is to stop that.
2. You are calling `setTimeout` recursivly which is not ideal for creating animations. Instead initiate all the `setTimeout`s you need for the entire animation at the same time with increasing delays in a loop and let them run their course, or better yet use `setInterval` which is the better way of doing animations, and how for instance jQuery's animations work.
3. It looks like you are trying to redraw the entire `canvas` at each step of your animation - this is not optimal, try only manipulation the pixels that change. The link you have given to "more challanging canvas scripts" are actually a lot simpler than what you are trying to do, since it's all vector based math - which is what the `canvas` element is optimized for - it was never made to do full re-rendering every x milliseconds, and it likely never will be.
4. If what you really need to do is changing the entire image for every frame in your animation - don't use `canvas` but normal image tags with preloaded images, then it will run smoothly in ie6 on a singlecore atom.

Comment: 1. Obviously I didn't start with that, but it did prove to be the best performance. 2. No difference, and I've never seen that approach actually. 3.  The canvascape (3d 'fps' game) does have a clearRect everytime the player moves, doesn't that make it redraw the entire canvas? 4. I draw a shape, which needs to have dynamic proportions.

Comment: Multiple timeouts is a bit weird and hardly maintainable. I would suggest a tomeout of 20ms (to obtain 50 fps) and have just one global function called that manages all the animations in place.

Comment: @UVL: I agree, setInterval is the way to go for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an app that works kind of like Google maps - it lets you click and pan over a large image.  I redraw my Canvas heavily, sampling and scaling from a big image each redraw.

Anyway, I happened to try a dual canvas approach - drawing to a (larger) buffer one when needed, then doing a canvas_display.drawImage(canvas_buffer) to output a region to the screen.  Not only did I not see a performance gain, but it got significantly slower with the iPhone.  Just a datapoint...

Answer (score 0):

OK, first things first. What *else* is happening while you're doing this animation? Any other javascript, any other timers, any other handlers? The answer, by the way, cannot be *nothing*. Your browser is repainting the window - the bits you're changing, at least. If other javascript is 'running', remember, that's not strictly true. Javascript is single-threaded by design. You can only *queue for execution*, so if some other javascript is hogging the thread, you won't get a look in.

Secondly, learn about how timers work. http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ is my personal favorite post on this. In particular, `setTimeout` is asking the browser to run something after *at least* the specified time, but only when the browser has an opening to do that.

Third, know what you're doing with `function(){animate(i+1);}`. That anonymous function can *only* exist within the scope of its parent. In other words, when you queue up a function like this, the parent scope still exists on the callstack, as @MartinJespersen pointed out. And since that function queues up another, and another, and another... each is going to get progressively slower.

I've put everything discussed in a little fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KzGRT/

(the first time I've ever used jsfiddle, so be kind). It's a simple 10-frame animation at (nominally) 100ms, using `setTimeout` for each. (I've done it this way instead of `setInterval` because, in theory, the one that takes longer to execute should start lagging behind the others. *In theory* - again, because javascript is single-threaded, if one slows down, it would delay the others as well).

The top method just has all ten images drawn on overlapping canvases, with only one showing at a time. Animation is just hiding the previous frame and showing the next. The second performs the `putImageData` into a canvas with a top-level function. The third uses an anonymous function as you tried. Watch for the red flash on frame zero, and you'll see who is executing the quickest - for me, it takes a while, but they eventually begin to drift (in Chrome, on a decent machine. It should be more obvious in FF on something lower-spec).

Try it on your low-end test machine and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I did the setTimeout this way, hope it helps somebody at boosting application:

```
var do = true;
var last = false;
window.onmousemove = function(evt){
    E.x = evt.pageX - cvs.offsetLeft;
    E.y = evt.pageY - cvs.offsetTop;
    if(do){
        draw();
        do = false;
        //in 23 ms drawing enabled again
        var t = setTimeout(function(){do = true;},23);
    }else{
        //the last operation must be done to catch the cursor point
        clearTimeout(last );
        last = setTimeout(function(){draw();},23);
    }
};
```